# How can I convert 2 PHP arrays into 1 JSON object array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have these two arrays.

```
$arr1 = array(
   [0] => "ABC",
   [1] => "DEF",
   [2] => "GHI",
);

$arr2 = array(
   [0] => 'Y',
   [1] => 'N',
   [2] => 'Y',
);
```

And I want to convert these arrays into one JSON object array like below.

```
[ 
  { "contents" : "ABC", "open": "Y" },
  { "contents" : "DEF", "open": "N" },
  { "contents" : "GHI", "open": "Y" },
]
```

I googled it and it suggested me using the json_encode function, but it didn't give me the result I wanted.

Comment: Show the code that you tried.

Answer (score 2):

Simple as:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[] = ['contents' => $value, 'open' => $arr2[$key]];
}
echo json_encode($newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

glad to help!

I think you've used `json_encode` in a wrong way.

Please try my code below:

```php
$arr1 = array(
   [0] => "ABC",
   [1] => "DEF",
   [2] => "GHI",
);

$arr2 = array(
   [0] => 'Y',
   [1] => 'N',
   [2] => 'Y',
);

$json_tmp = [];
for ( $i=0; $i<sizeof($arr1); $i++) {
    $json_tmp = ['contents' => $arr1[$i], 'open' => $arr2[$i]];
}

echo json_encode($json_tmp);
```

Wish you a good day:)